# importing pouchdb into angular4

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, pouchdb, definitelytyped

#### The Issue:

Not able to import pouchdb in angular4
running ng serve in angular cli (that should compile the typescript and make the page run) gives the error

when using pouchddb

> Cannot find module 'pouchdb'. webpack: Failed to compile.

and when using pouchdb-browswer

> Cannot find module 'pouchdb-browser'. webpack: Failed to compile.

#### Reproduce

1- Install angular cli

```
npm install angluar-cli -g
```

2- Create angular project

```
ng new project
```

3- In the project install pouch
either

```
npm install pouchdb --save
```

or

```
npm install pouchdb-browser --save
```

In the code import pouch db

tried each of these but all gave the same error

```
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb-browser';
import * as PouchDB from 'pouchdb-browser';
import * as PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
```

#### Note

Installing @types/pouchdb didn't help, infact I get even more compilation errors
some of the errors are

```
ERROR in C:/Users/aallawati/Development/pro1/node_modules/@types/pouchdb-core/index.d.ts (765,30): Cannot find namespace 'Core'.

ERROR in C:/Users/aallawati/Development/pro1/node_modules/@types/pouchdb-core/index.d.ts (766,37): Cannot find namespace 'Core'.

ERROR in C:/Users/aallawati/Development/pro1/node_modules/@types/pouchdb-core/index.d.ts (767,40): Cannot find namespace 'Core'.

ERROR in C:/Users/aallawati/Development/pro1/node_modules/@types/pouchdb-core/index.d.ts (768,33): Cannot find namespace 'Core'.

ERROR in C:/Users/aallawati/Development/pro1/node_modules/@types/pouchdb-core/index.d.ts (771,30): Cannot find namespace 'Core'.

ERROR in C:/Users/aallawati/Development/pro1/node_modules/@types/pouchdb-core/index.d.ts (772,37): Cannot find namespace 'Core'.

ERROR in C:/Users/aallawati/Development/pro1/node_modules/@types/pouchdb-core/index.d.ts (773,41): Cannot find namespace 'Core'.

ERROR in C:/Users/aallawati/Development/pro1/node_modules/@types/pouchdb-core/index.d.ts (776,30): Cannot find namespace 'Core'.

ERROR in C:/Users/aallawati/Development/pro1/node_modules/@types/pouchdb-core/index.d.ts (777,37): Cannot find namespace 'Core'.

ERROR in C:/Users/aallawati/Development/pro1/node_modules/@types/pouchdb-core/index.d.ts (778,33): Cannot find namespace 'Core'.



ERROR in C:/Users/aallawati/Development/pro1/node_modules/@types/pouchdb-replication/index.d.ts (166,45): '>' expected.

ERROR in C:/Users/aallawati/Development/pro1/node_modules/@types/pouchdb-replication/index.d.ts (166,47): Expression expected.

ERROR in C:/Users/aallawati/Development/pro1/node_modules/@types/pouchdb-replication/index.d.ts (186,13): ',' expected.

ERROR in C:/Users/aallawati/Development/pro1/node_modules/@types/pouchdb-replication/index.d.ts (191,10): ',' expected.
```

#### update

i tried to import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';  in a normal typescript file (non angular)

and compiled it with tsc  and it worked fine

i guess the issue is because of angular-cli or webpack not sure

Comment: Can you please list the compilation errors? installing it is mandatory for the db to work, but the compilation errors might get fixed.

Comment: @Supamiu  sorry i ment installing @types/pouchdb  causes compilation error , any how this shouldn't be must and found some refrences on the net showing that the @types/pouchdb is not synced with the latest version of pouchdb  that could be the reason for the errors

Comment: Using CLI v1.2.0 with Angular v4.3.3 and _import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';_ does work for me.

Comment: @PerfectPixel  OMG i can't believe it  , all my issue was because of CLI verson i was using angular-cli ,  1.0.0   , just now i changed to @angular/cli and it is working perfectly  can you add this as answer so i can reword you the bounty amount

Comment: Always happy to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CLI v1.2.0 with Angular v4.3.3 and `import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';` does work for me.

Keep in mind that the package was renamed at a certain point and only the newer versions support more advanced webpack configurations.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with Typescript(Angular or ionic) make sure you run these commands

`npm install pouchdb @types/pouchdb` and add `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` in your tsconfig.json file.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  }
}
```

Then import in your providers with

```
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
```